# Python xlsxwriter: How do I write a formula that references a different sheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel-formula, openoffice-calc, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to add a excel file that includes a formula referencing
a different sheet.

In this example, I try to copy the word "world" from sheet 2 to sheet 1.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet(name='Sheet 1')
sheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet(name='Sheet 2')
sheet2.write(2,2,'world')
sheet1.write(2,2,'hello')
sheet1.write_formula('D3', "='Sheet 2'.C3")

workbook.close()
```

The resulting xlsx file, when openened, displays the fomula in 
lower case. The formula does not work when I press Ctrl+Shift+F9 
to recalculate all formulas.

If I type the formula manually, it works.

Is is possible to reference others sheets when creating xlsxwriter excel files?

I'm using Open Office 5 to display the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula needs to be in the US Excel syntax, like the following (note `!` not `.`):

```
sheet1.write_formula('D3', "='Sheet 2'!C3")
```

See the [Working with Formulas](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html) section of the XlsxWriter docs.